# Problema con subconsulta SQL con varios campos

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas. Una se llama diccionario y otra diccionario_auxiliar. En diccionario tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
id_diccionario INT PK
proveedor VAR_CHAR(50)
categoria VAR_CHAR(50)
familia_erp INT
subfamilia_erp INT
```

En diccionario_auxiliar tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
ean CHAR (13) PK
marca VARCHAR (30)
categoria VARCHAR (500)
familia_erp INT
subfamilia_erp INT
```

Pues bien, lo que quiero es coger de diccionario familia_erp y subfamilia_erp (en diccionario_auxiliar ahora esos campos están vacíos) y quiero cogerlos según su marca y su categoría. El fin es luego insertarlos en diccionario_auxiliar. La consulta que estoy haciendo es:

```
SELECT 
familia_erp, subfamilia_erp 
FROM diccionario 
WHERE (SELECT marca, categoria FROM diccionario_auxiliar);
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutarla da error y me dice que el operando debe tener una columna. Pero no veo el fallo. ¿En qué estoy fallando? Gracias.

```
SELECT 
familia_erp, subfamilia_erp 
FROM diccionario 
WHERE categoria=(SELECT categoria FROM diccionario_auxiliar) 
AND proveedor=(SELECT marca FROM diccionario_auxiliar);
```

También he probado esta consulta pero me dice que la subconsulta devuelve más de una línea.

P.D. Ahora mismo sólo estoy intentando coger los datos, luego ya los insertaré en diccionario_auxiliar. Gracias.

EJEMPLO PARA QUE SE ME ENTIENDA:

```
Tabla Diccionario

Id: 1
Proveedor: Sony
Categoria: Sonido
Familia_ERP: 300
Subfamilia_erp: 20

Tabla diccionario_auxiliar:

Ean: 1234567890123
Marca: Sony
Categoria: Sonido
Familia_erp: NULL
Subfamilia_erp: NULL
```

Básicamente yo quiero que me busque en la tabla diccionario en este ejemplo la marca Sony y la categoría Sonido, y me coja la familia_erp y la subfamilia_erp que corresponde, para posteriormente insertarlo en la tabla diccionario_auxiliar.
NOTA: proveedor en diccionario es lo mismo que marca en diccionario_auxiliar.

Comment: ¿Esto `FROM diccionario WHERE (SELECT categoria,` no esta incompleto?, es decir ¿que columna evalúa el `WHERE`?

Comment: where que cosa? que tratas que haga ese where?

Comment: es correcto... SELECT proveedor FROM diccionario_auxiliar esto devuelve todos los proveedores de esa tabla. tal vez con unos ejemplos entendamos mejor que queres hcer?

Comment: A ver, básicamente en diccionario tengo un proveedor y una categoría, que se corresponden con proveedor y categoría de diccionario_auxiliar. Yo quiero coger de diccionario la familia_erp y la subfamilia_erp del registro proveedor y categoría que coincide con el registro proveedor y categoría y diccionario auxiliar. ¿Se entiende?

Comment: La primera consulta dice WHERE (salida de subconsulta); te falta una comparación lógica (eso debe ser igual a qué o cómo debe ser la salida de la subconsulta). La segunda ya hace esa comparación pero el error te dice claramente que no tiene sentido hacer una comparación lógica entre cada registro en su columna categoría y una lista. ¿Querrías usar IN (no sé si IN exista en mysql)? Se entiende el lío en tu intento?

Comment: IN existe, pero tampoco tiene sentido.. yo no veo proveedor en diccionario auxiliar...

Comment: y tu idea es hacer una consulta que actulice dicc auxiliar o solo el select?

Comment: Marca y categoria son el mismo valor, aunque el campo se llame distinto se me olvidó decirlo. Lo primero es hacer la consulta, que luego meto los datos en un array y ya los insertaré en la tabla diccionario_auxiliar.

Comment: por algo en particular??? porque te alcanza con hacer un update en sql...

Comment: Yo he planteado esto porque creo que es la mejor forma de hacerlo, pero si se puede hacer con un update y es más fácil mejor que mejor.

Comment: si.. te recomendaria leer sobre sql para que entiendas mejor que se puede hacer con el... ya te pongo una respuesta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas hacer un update a tu tabla diccionario auxiliar...

```
Update diccionario_auxiliar a 
    inner join diccionario d 
        on d.proveedor = a.marca and d.categoria = a.categoria 
set a.Familia_ERP = d.Familia_ERP, a.Subfamilia_erp = d.Subfamilia_erp
```

en esta query, le decimos que actualice los registros de diccionario_auxiliar, usando como base los registros de diccionario...

y en el set, le decimos que campos actualizar y con que valores...

si hay datos repetidos entre las tablas, esto va a fallar...

Comment: Mil gracias. Funciona de lujo y no hay problemas de datos repetidos (si un dato está repetido, se le pone la misma familia_erp y subfamilia_erp y listo, no hay problema). Muchas gracias.